# GET HTTP request Android Studio

Tags: java, http, junit

I am writing a java test for an Android device in the androidTest directory. I need to perform an http get request ON MY computer. But for some reason my method is executed on a connected Android phone.

```
public class HttpRequests {
    @Test
    public void dropSession() throws IOException {
        String url = "url.url";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected response code: " + response);
            }

            String responseBody = response.body().string();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But for some reason your method is _not_ executed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your test on your computer rather than connected Android phone, then you should put your test code into the `src/test` instead of `src/androidTest`